# Resizing video clips with moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy

I've been using moviepy to create an auto editor for putting a clip on top and a clip on the bottom. I'm having trouble resizing my clips. It won't allow me to use the resize command when I import it over. This is the code I am using:

````
import os
import random
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, CompositeVideoClip, concatenate_videoclips , clips_array, vfx, AudioFileClip, ImageClip 
from moviepy.video.fx import resize


originalFolder = "c:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Content Software\\testfold"
list = os.listdir(originalFolder)

minecraftFolder = "c:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Content Software\\minecraft"

minecraftList = os.listdir(minecraftFolder)

def videoGen(minecraftList, list):
    clipIndex = int(random.random()*len(list))
    filePath1 = os.path.join(originalFolder, list[clipIndex])

    overlayClip = VideoFileClip(filePath1)
    minecraftIndex = int(random.random()*len(minecraftList))
    filePath2 = os.path.join(originalFolder, list[minecraftIndex])

    minecraftClip = VideoFileClip(filePath2)

    clips = ([overlayClip], [minecraftClip])

    combined = clips_array(clips)

    combinedFinal = resize(combined, width=1080, height=1920)

    combinedFinal.write_videofile("test.mp4")
    
    
videoGen(minecraftList, list)```



I keep getting this error message every time  I run the command: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\me\Desktop\Content Software\Minecraft Video Gen.py", line 33, in <module>
    videoGen(minecraftList, list)
  File "c:\Users\me\Desktop\Content Software\Minecraft Video Gen.py", line 28, in videoGen
    combinedFinal = resize(combined, width=1080, height=1920)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

What is it that I'm doing wrong that's causing my code to break? using combined.resize() hasn't worked for me either, I'm really confused because nothing in the docs are solving my problem.
````

Comment: maybe there is conflict with resize()?
Can you try this:
`from moviepy.video.fx import resize as video_resize`
and change it like this:
`combinedFinal = video_resize(combined, width=1080, height=1920)`

Also when you try `combined.resize()` what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the resize method:

`combinedFinal.resize((1080, 1920))`

If an error related to ANTIALIAS pops up it's due to the version of PIL. Explanation and fixing method in this github thread: [thread](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/2002)